# Playframework How to transform query.ResultList to VO

Tags: jpa, playframework, transform

The version of Playframework is 1.2.x,and I want to transform the query.ResultList to VO.

I created a Part entity bean as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="evaluation_part")
public class Part extends Model {

    public String name;  

    public String collegeName;

    public int peopleNum;
}
```

The data:

```
id     name     collegeName      peopleNum

1      Jsj1     JJJJ              32
2      Jsj2     JJJJ              23
3      Jsj3     JJJJ              32
4      Tjb1     TTTT              11
5      Tjb2     TTTT              14
6      Tjb3     TTTT              16
```

My value object class:

```
public class PartVO {

    public String collegeName;

    public int peopleNum;

}
```

And I want to use the native query to get the result:

```
String sql="select collegeName,SUM(peopleNum) as peopleNum from evaluation_part group by collegeName";
```

The query result is:

```
      collegeName      peopleNum

        TTTT              41
        JJJJ              87
```

I tried：

```
String sql="select collegeName,SUM(peopleNum) as peopleNum from evaluation_part group by collegeName";

Query query =JPA.em().createNativeQuery(sql);

List<PartVO> partVOs = query.getResultList();
for(int i=0;i<partVOs.size();i++) {      
    System.out.println(partVOs.get(i).collegeName);
}
```

Following error is what i am getting

```
ClassCastException occured : [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to valueobject.PartVO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:Only use 'select new Part()'(constructor defined in the Part class) in the HQL that u can  convert object to Part.Hibernate use reflection to automatically inject all the fields u need.

Solution 2:Here the returned type of result must be Object[],so that u can got every field of the record fetched from database by the index of array;

The difference between solution1 and solution2:the previous use constructor in the query and the later transform a record into Object[].

In your case,ignore the complex relationship between entities,solutions above will make work.

Referenced Code here:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;
import play.mvc.*;
import java.util.*;

import models.*;

/**
* This demo is intended for fetching data from MYSQL.
* @author dhl@oopsplay.org
*/

public class Application extends Controller {

public static void index() {
    render();
}

/**
 * Prepare some data to test.
 */
public static void addPart() {

    //Add a part record to database.
    Part newPart=new Part("software","zjut",8).save();
    if(newPart.isPersistent()){
        renderText("Add successfully,there are %s records in the \'evaluation_part\' table.For convenience,please click the back button in the browser to go back previous page.",Part.count());
    }
}

/**
 * Fetch part entities from database;
 */
public static void fetchPart() {

    //-------------------Solution 1-------------------
    //[Pay attention]:Only use 'select new Part()'(constructor defined in the Part class) in the query that u can  convert object to Part.
    //Hibernate use reflection to automatically inject all the fields u need.
    List<Part> parts1=JPA.em().createQuery("select new Part(name,collegeName,peopleNum) from Part").getResultList();

    //For convenience, i output the detail in the console, focus on the change there.
    Logger.info("The name of first record is :%s", parts1.get(0).name);

    //-------------------Solution 2-------------------
    //[Pay attention]:Here the returned type of result must be Object[],so that u can got every field of the record fetched from database;
    List<Object[]> parts2=JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select name,collegeName,peopleNum from evaluation_part").getResultList();
    Logger.info("The name of first record is :%s", parts2.get(0)[0]);

    for(int i=0;i<parts2.size();i++){

        //The difference between solution1 and solution2:the previous use constructor in the query and the later transform a record into Object[].
        Logger.info("Name from parts1 is: %s", parts1.get(i).name);
        Logger.info("Name from parts2 is: %s", parts2.get(i)[0]);
    }

    renderText("There are %s record in the \'evaluation_part\' table",parts2.size());
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to user raw sql to do that. With hql you can use the new operator to create your VO (see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)

You have to define a two arg constructor in your partVO class, then you can do

```
select new package.PartVO(collegeName, SUM(peopleNum)) from Part group by collegeName
```

Comment: I don't think you can use HQL (Hibernate query language) with Play Framework which uses JPA.

Comment: Sure you can, Play 1.2.x uses hibernate underneath. I use this technique all over my application without trouble

Answer (score 0):

You can use the version of createNativeQuery(...) method that also accepts as argument the Class of the result instance(s):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class).

However make sure this actually works, as Play Framework doesn't implement all the features of JPA in it's implementation of the API.